# Long if() statements using && operators, or separate if statements?

Tags: java

```
   if(this.x > tempObject.x - 32 && this.x < tempObject.x && this.y > tempObject.y - 32 && this.y < tempObject.y){
```

Should i leave if() statements like this or should i break them into 2 lines ? Which one is more efficient ?

Comment: There is no difference in efficiency, only readability. I would break it over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can break the if statement into multiple lines completely without breaking it into multiple if statements in order to make it more readable:

```java
if(this.x > tempObject.x - 32 
    && this.x < tempObject.x 
    && this.y > tempObject.y - 32 
    && this.y < tempObject.y)
```

You could also format it so that the operators are at the end of each line, but that's a stylistic question. I personally prefer this format, because with the start of the line it is immediately clear what operator is used.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if(this.x > tempObject.x - 32 && this.x < tempObject.x && this.y > tempObject.y - 32 && this.y < tempObject.y){ ... }
```

is semantically identical to this:

```
if(this.x > tempObject.x - 32 && this.x < tempObject.x
    && this.y > tempObject.y - 32 && this.y < tempObject.y){ ... }
```

is semantically identical to this

```
if(this.x > tempObject.x - 32 && this.x < tempObject.x) {
    if (this.y > tempObject.y - 32 && this.y < tempObject.y){ ... }
}
```

There is no difference in performance, because they all compile to the same bytecode.

Choose the one you find most readable.

Answer (score 0):

its the same thing for the compiler, but just for more lisibility for the developer its better to break it into lines.